# How to apply CSS correctly to iFrame?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Folks, i have the following problem.
My website uses an iframe to select an element aso...
The important thing is that FF (and Chrome) renders the css correctly while IE seems to not apply it or at least parts of it.

I placed a simplified example of my site [here](http://thariama.th.ohost.de/ie2.html):  http://thariama.th.ohost.de/ie2.html
Please have a look using FF and IE. You need to click on "Click me!" and the iframe opens up.

To be honest, it does not look very nice, but thats because i stripped out as much as possible out of the more complex website.
There is a lense image right of the input field X2. 
In FF it gets displayed and it gets replaced with another image if the user types in three letters. In IE nothing happens, also other css-settings have not been applied as you can see.

**What i can do to make IE apply the css too?**

Comment: When I try to click in Fx I just get the error `$("#" + this.id).dialog is not a function`.

Comment: i will have a closer look, looks like something is still missing in the stripped down version

Comment: the example works now, after i added a few javascript files i stripped at first

Comment: wierd, i don't (maybe you need to clear your cache) - but i found out at least what the problem of all this was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding a doctype definition to `ie2.html`. Seems like IE uses an own one if none is defined what leads to a different css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Remove the XML tag though, or some versions of IE will ignore the doctype.